# Why is 'u' in "study" short if the 'u' in "student" is long?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation-vs-spelling

Why is 'u' in "study" short if the 'u' in "student" is long? Both come from Latin "studere", right? In Latin, the 'u' in "studere" is short.

Comment: Because English spelling doesn't represent English pronunciation. You shouldn't expect consistency; there isn't any. It's been a long time since Latin, and every word has its own unique history, leading to different pronunciations. What changes most and most reliably is **sounds**, and that's what linguists study.

Comment: Both have a fairly complex origin, involving repeated French and Latin influences. But it's not unusual for vowels to be lengthened or shortened depending on the environment. I suggest you do some research into the etymology of both words; https://www.etymonline.com/ is a start but the OED has more details.

Comment: @Lambie - I might have a minute disagreement with that.

Comment: How about the u in minute? m[i]n[i][t]. As in minutes in an hour. No "u" sound at all. English phonemes are not like Spanish. They have many realizations which you have to learn and practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's most likely because the verb *study* was borrowed earlier than the noun *student.*

The Oxford English Dictionary says that *study* may in part be from an Old English borrowing from Latin. Old English, like Latin, had vowel length, and so it would be expected to adopt Latin short u as an Old English short u sound (which then would undergo the same changes as other instances of short u).

Another possible contributing source to *study* is Old French *(e)studier.* Old French had lost vowel length, and its vowels could be taken into Middle English as short or long vowels.

The form *student,* per the Oxford English Dictionary, is from "post-classical Latin *student-, studens* person engaged in study (frequently from 1231 in British sources; also in continental sources)". The earliest spellings ending in *-dent* (as opposed to *-dient/-dyent/-diaunt* etc., which the OED treats as older variants of the same word) appear to occur in the 1400s, based on the OED's citations. The pronunciation of u as the "long u" sound is consistent with what Wikipedia calls the "[Traditional English pronunciation of Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_English_pronunciation_of_Latin)". That pronunciation doesn't follow Latin vowel quantities at all, except indirectly in that they affected the position of stress in Latin words of more than two syllables.